# Concatenating nested classes using SASS

Tags: sass

I am trying to use the nesting feature of SASS to concatenate two classes, but can't figure out how to do it.

**This is the HTML:**

```
<section class="a">
    <div class="b">
        <div class="c date">some date</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Here is my current SASS:**

```
.a .c
    display: inline-block

    .date
        width: 50px
```

**It creates the following CSS:**

```
.a .c {
    display: inline-block;
}
.a .c .date {
    width: 50px;
}
```

But this doesn't work. The browser expects the "date" and "string-long" to be nested under the "c" class  rather than them being both existent on the same HTML tag.

What I need is this (**no space between .c and .date => .c.date**):

```
.a .c {
    display: inline-block;
}
.a .c.date {
    width: 50px;
}
```

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [*&*](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand)

You can achieve this with the [**ampersand**](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand) operator. Try:

```
.a .c
  display: inline-block

  &.date
    width: 50px
```

The ampersand is a placeholder for parent selectors. And if you don't place a space after it in a nested selector it will output a concatenated selector (just what you want).

#### [DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7438348)

---

<sup>**Note:** in deeper nested selectors `&` stands for the whole path of nested selectors not just for the immediate parent.</sup>